# simple regex issue

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have two almost idential expressions and I'm getting one good and another way wrong output.

```
data/holidays/photos-2012-2013/word-another-more-more-5443/"><span class="bold">word another</span> - word</a>    

regex = 'data/holidays/photos-2012-2013/.+?(\d{4})/"><span class="bold">(.+?)</span>(.+?)</a>'
```

`word-another-more-more`, `word another` and `word`, this all in the above changes.
The above prints out correctly, a list of tuples like this:
`('6642', 'word another', ' - word')`

```
data/holidays/photos-2012-2013/word-another-more-more-5443/">word- another - <span class="bold">word another</span></a>

regex1 = 'data/holidays/photos-2012-2013/.+?(\d{4})/">(.+?)<span class="bold">(.+?)</span></a>'
```

This above prints out some trash code, despite the syntax used is idential. Output is a list containing tuples too, but is full of unwanted code.

Can you see what's wrong about the second regex?

Comment: Please do not try to parse HTML with regular expressions. Why not use a HTML parser instead?

Comment: If it's so simple, why do you need help? :-)

Comment: I agree with Martijn Pieters, using a regex is almost guaranteed to fail for parsing HTML; you're much more likely to succeed if you can use an XML/HTML parser instead.  That aside, as a general suggestion I'd say try running your input through the simulator at http://regexpal.com/ and see if your regex works the way you think it does.

Comment: @neilr8133 thanks for the regexpal. Seems very helpful. My code seems to be working well but not in real world ;/

Comment: i actually figured it out right now. anyway thanks for suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'data/holidays/photos-2012-2013/word-another-more-more-5443/">word- another - <span class="bold">word another</span></a>'
>>> re.findall(r'data/holidays/photos-2012-2013/.+?(\d{4})/">(.+?)<span class="bold">(.+?)</span></a>', text)
[('5443', 'word- another - ', 'word another')]
```

Note: *please* don't parse HTML with regex. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) exists just for this reason.